# Cant figure out how to display alphabets in order from a to z using linked list in c++

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

```
void alphaout()
 {
   nodealpha *curr;
   nodealpha *curr2;
   curr = first;
   curr2 = first;

while (curr != NULL)
 {
   char al1 = curr2 -> alpha;
   char al2 = curr -> alpha;
   if (al1 < al2)
    {
      curr2 = curr;
    }
 std::cout << "ALPHABET : " << curr -> alpha << endl;
 curr = curr -> next;
 }
}
```

I have made a simple program where the user inputs each alphabets and then display it in their order regardless of however way the user inputs the alphabets but the problem is that when it diplays the alphabets are in the same order in which the user has given input I cant figure out how to arrange it in a to z way

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two different ways of going about this, first one, you could save the addresses of your nodes in an array using the index of their ascii code:

```
// here is a function i made for an old project which will give you the index in an array 
//of any char you pass to it (sorry for spanish comments but that's my my teacher 
//asked for)
int position(char letter)
{
    int valor;
    //A-ascii 65 -> posicion 0  a-ascii 97 -> 0
    //Z-ascii 90 -> posicion 25  z->ascii 122 - 25
    if(letra>='A' && letra <='Z')
        valor = letra - 65;
    else if(letra >='a' && letra<='z')
        valor = letra-97;
    else
        valor= 26; //
    return valor;
}


// this is what i would put in your alphaout function to store the ponters
// here we save the pointers to each letter
nodealpha *alpha[size of your aplhabet];

while(curr != NULL){
    alpha[position(curr->alpha)] = curr;
    curr = curr->next;
}
// after this you can just print the array
cout << "alphabet: " << endl;
for(int i = 0; i < (size of alphabet); i++){
    cout << alpha[i]->alph << ", ";
}
```

the downside with this is that it will not account for duplicates, it willonly dabe the last instance of every letter

as for the other method you can sweep your list once for every letter of your alphabet and  print it at the moment, but this will take noticeably more time to do, but it will acount for duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Since characters are made of `ASCII` and `ASCII` is composed of numbers, we may first convert `char` types into `int` type inside an array, and then by using `qsort()` we may rearrange them properly. And then convert them into `char` anew whilst rearranged.

The following code is an example:

```
#include <iostream>      
#include <cstdlib>     
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main ()
{
   std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
   std::string order;

   std::cout << "Input the alphabet order: ";
   std::getline(std::cin, order);

   int Alphabet[26];
   std::string::iterator iter;
   for(iter = order.begin();iter != order.end(); iter++){
        Alphabet[order.find(*iter)] = *iter; 
   }

   qsort (Alphabet, order.length(), sizeof(int), [](const void* a, const void* b)->int{
       return (*(int*)a - *(int*)b );
   });

   std::vector<int> Filter;
   for(int x = 0; x < order.length(); x++){
      if(std::find(Filter.begin(), Filter.end(), Alphabet[x]) == Filter.end()){
        Filter.push_back(Alphabet[x]); // to filter out repetitive characters.
      }
   }

   std::vector<int>::iterator Iter;
   std::cout << "ALPHABET: ";
   for(Iter = Filter.begin(); Iter != Filter.end(); Iter++){
      std::cout << static_cast<char>(*Iter); 
   }
   std::cout << std::endl;

   return 0;

}
```

Comment: *"Since characters are made of `ASCII`"* - That's unfounded. C++ does not specify or mandate any particular character encoding. In particular, C++ does not specify any particular order of the numeric value of a `char` and the character it resembles. If you disagree, please provide supporting evidence for your statements.